# how to hear the embedded flv audio in flash timeline

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flv

Simple question I know but I can't find any relevant answer on Stack...
I have an embedded flv in my flash timeline. When I export/test as swf I can hear the audio.
When I hit enter/return and the timeline runs, I see the video playing but I can't hear the audio!!! If I click on the timeline to get the sound properties there are no options - Effect and sync are greyed out.
Can you please help? I need to hear the audio in the timeline to sync the animation 
Thanks

Comment: been awhile since i used flash pro but i dont think you can - the sound properties are for sound files, not audio of video files

Comment: okay, thanks. Its not surprising as I've had real trouble trying to do it. what a shame, its very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Unless anyone can assert otherwise the answer is that you can't do it. I ended up doing this project in quicktime pro instead

Answer (score 0):

separate out the audio file from the video and import it as a sound file onto the time line to sync your animation, delete the sound track when you finish. make sure the FPS is the same as the original animation or the sound will go out of sync